# How to do server verification for PayPal Adaptive (MPL) Payment

Tags: ios, mobile, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We got PayPal Adaptive payments working on our iOS app using MPL due to the requirement to support Parallel payments to PayPal accounts other than our own.

**My question is where do I find documentation that teaches server side verification of the Adaptive payments?**

My understanding of the flows is:

1. Our Mobile App calls MPL, which handles payment.
2. MPL returns a success payKey to Mobile App
3. Mobile App forward payKey to our Server
4. Our server checks the payKey with PayPal to verify payment with PayPal
5. Our server returns a status back to Mobile App with a success / failure code from PayPal check in (4)
6. Our Mobile app is happy, does some funky dance moves and proceeds to start on the order fulfilment side of things

**I'm wondering where documentation is for Step (4)?**

**Alternately, how have you done server side payment validation?**

I sense fraud issues if we skipped steps (4) onwards...

Following links don't seem to apply to MPL libraries directly:

- Verify PayPal payment when using mobile SDK (RESTful API, not MPL)
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/
- Getting started with mobile MPL page doesn't talk about a server verification step
  https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/
- PayPal MPL Developer guide & ref manual doesn't talk about a server verification step
  https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_mpl_developer_guide_and_reference_iphone.pdf

Any help would be appreciated!

*EDIT:* formatting